# How to capture and replace strings with regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I try to capture and replace strings with regex in notepad++, but the result is not as expected. The database is formatted like this:

```
(602, '0602', '[{"id":"9","value":""},{"id":"1","value":"1"}]'),
(1644, '0164', '[{"id":"9","value":""},{"id":"1","value":"3"}]'),
(1311, '0131', '[{"id":"9","value":""},{"id":"1","value":"100"}]'),
(1321, '0132', '[{"id":"9","value":""},{"id":"1","value":"150"}]')
```

The task is to capture and place column 2 (values 0602, 0164, 0131, 0131) and to insert it as value of id 9. For example, end result must be like this:

```
(602, '0602', '[{"id":"9","value":"0602"},{"id":"1","value":"1"}]'),
(1644, '0164', '[{"id":"9","value":"0164"},{"id":"1","value":"3"}]'),
(1311, '0131', '[{"id":"9","value":"0131"},{"id":"1","value":"100"}]'),
(1321, '0132', '[{"id":"9","value":"0132"},{"id":"1","value":"150"}]')
```

I try with this regex in Notepad++ - Search:

```
(, '.*)("id":"9","value":"")
```

Replace:

```
($1)("id":"9","value":"$1")
```

The result is close, but not what I need. Please, help me if you know the right answer. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use below regex to capture the parts of the string and replace it by the second column value

```
^(\(\d+,\s*.*?(\d+).*?value":).*?([,}])
```

And use `\1"\2"\3` as the replacement part.

[**Live Demo on RegEx101**](https://regex101.com/r/pfD4Ia/2)

**Explanation:**

1. `^`: Start of line
2. `\(`: Match `(` literal
3. `\d+,\s*`: Match digit/s followed by comma and any number of spaces
4. `.*?`: Match anything to satisfy the following condition
5. `(\d+)`: Match one or more digits and add them in captured group
6. `.*?value":`: Match till `value"`
7. `([,}])`: Match either `,` or `}`

The captured group `\1` will contain the string till `value":`, `"\2"` will contain the number in the second column in double quotes and `\3` will contain the last `,` or `}`.

Comment: Be careful, you are missing the quotation after the value in the replacement.

Comment: @Tushar, thank you very much for solution and for explanation. I will try it immediately.

Comment: @Tushar 100% working solution. I modify it slyghtly like this: Search:  ^(\(\d+,\s*.*?(\d+).*?value":").*?([,}])   Replace: \1\2"\3  Thanks again!

Comment: Nice! now I understand the function of '(' ')' Thanks!